# Hybrid android app code reuse for mobile web

Tags: java, android, cordova, maven, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm searching a way into world of hybrid mobile applications. I understand that hybrid android app uses some Webview which just shows HTML/javascript based webpage.

My background is maven, java, so for my application backend will be for sure in java, thats clear. But I'm not sure which way to go in case of the front-end and I have couple of questions emerging.

> 1. Can I somehow reuse the code between the android packaged hybrid app and the page served by the java backend for regular browsers(of
>      course without the android system function usage)?
> 2. Is it possible to manage it only via maven plugins or will I need to dig into npm, bower, grunt and such stuff(although I now lot of
>      them are already mavenized)?
> 3. Which js? framework to use? There are some already bound with cordova/phonegap(Ionic) and some that are standing aside(I like
>      Aurelia) which will probably be fine for web application, but for
>      android reusage it will not be easy to bound them with Cordova's
>      lifecycle. It is more about which kind not exactly about particular
>      .js framework selection. I.e. Can I just write some AngularJs
>      application for web and then extend it with Ionic?

I can imagine some structure like this in maven, note the communication to backend will be via WS

> - **app-java-backend** (is able to serve app-single-page-app)
> - **app-single-page-app** (this must support mobile and classical browsers)
> - **app-hybrid-mobile** (uses somehow the .js code from app-single-page-app)

UPDATE
Basically the question is about how to have common javascript base for hybrid app and same looking mobile page

UPDATE2
I can create mobile web app and then I will somehow bind with cordova. But how to do it properly using maven

Comment: Question is way too general. Basically you need a tutorial on these topics.

Comment: The question is not so vogue as it should like on first view. I'm not sure how to make me more clear. The mayor problem is can I build now hybrid application using maven, or do I really need to now about bower and such things? Can I use Webjars instead of npm dependencies etc.? Can I reuse the hybrid app code and serve it using application server? If any tutorial you might think of may help me don't hesitate to send it in.

Comment: I agree with the others. This question is too broad, too general.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `cordova-cli` to generate the project. Pay special attention to the *create* method and the --link-to option. that will allow you to use inside the cordova project the same folder that you use for the mobile site.

You do not need to do anything with maven by yourself as cordova can handle also other platforms than Android.

Comment: it is really good hidden feature I found something [here](http://devgirl.org/2014/02/10/3-cordova-cli-changes/). This is best hint so far.

Comment: And all must be in one maven project so maven will somehow invoke cordova cli

Answer (score 0):

Hybrid Apps are based on HTML,CSS and Javascript. if you want to use your backend with the hybrid app you need web services/webAPI 
so over all you need

Any UI Frame work  like bootstrap/Ionic
Javascript Frame work like Jquery/AngularJs
and Web services to access backend

Comment: The question is about hybrid mobile app and mobile web page which both are based on html. Hybrid app are just bundled mobile web pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share code(front end HTML CSS ) between your web app and mobile app, you sure can do that. For example design a button and add some CSS to it. You can always reuse the same button CSS served from server to any front end client you want.

Try with just writing code for your project, later you will get hold of things , where and what component you can reuse. To keep this simple what you have asked is possible.